# MySQL query group month into two periods

Tags: mysql

I want to do group select in MySQL, which is group my timestamp column into 2 periods of month and count each rows. just say, if there are rows in a month in date 1, 2 ,3, and also 17,19 in Sept it would be :

```
Period     count 
Sept 1     3 
Sept 2     2
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a gaps and islands problem, but in any case you show full data which covers edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 1 column period

```
SELECT period, count(period) AS count FROM table_name GROUP BY period
```

Comment: thanks, but it won't group timestamps into two periods

Comment: Can you please paste your schema with sample data and expected output

Comment: I just tested with time-stamp field and this query works fine too. So will be better if you paste your schema with sample data.